# Kafka JDBC source connector for Oracle DB - How to map nested json to avro schema

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka JDBC source connector (confluent.io) to get data from Oracle DB and push to kafka topic.

The DB table "test_table" has these columns.

```
create table test_table
(
json_obj varchar2(4000)
last_update_date DATE
)
```

JSON returned by this query has below structure.

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "department": {
    "deptId": "1",
    "deptName": "dept1"
  }
}
```

The Avro schema applied on the kafka topic is:

```
{
 "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "department",
      "type":[ 
        {
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "deptId",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "deptName",
              "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "name": "DeptObj",
          "type": "record"
        },"null"]
    }
  ],
  "name": "EmpObj",
  "namespace": "com.test",
  "type": "record"
}
```

And I am using the below connector config.

```
{
  "name": "JdbcSourceConnectorConnector_0",
  "config": {
    "schema.registry.url": "<schema-reg-url>",
    "name": "JdbcSourceConnectorConnector_0",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ldap-connect-string>/<db-name>",
    "connection.user": "<db-schema-name>",
    "connection.password": "<db-pwd>",
    "numeric.mapping": "best_fit",
    "dialect.name": "OracleDatabaseDialect",
    "mode": "timestamp",
    "timestamp.column.name": "last_update_date",
    "validate.non.null": "false",
    "query": "SELECT * FROM (SELECT JSON_VALUE(json_obj, '$.empId') as \"empId\", JSON_VALUE(json_obj, '$.department.deptId') as \"department.deptId\", JSON_VALUE(json_obj, '$.department.deptName') as \"department.deptName\" FROM test_table) A",
    "table.types": "TABLE",
    "poll.interval.ms": "30000",
    "topic.prefix": "<my-topic>",
    "db.timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "key.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
    "value.serializer": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer",
    "transforms": "createKeyStruct,ExtractField, addNamespace",
    "transforms.createKeyStruct.fields": "empId",
    "transforms.createKeyStruct.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "transforms.ExtractField.field": "empId",
    "transforms.ExtractField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.addNamespace.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value",
    "transforms.addNamespace.schema.name": "EmpObj"
  }
}
```

But when this connector gets the json data then it throws the below error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: department.deptId
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.validateName(Schema.java:1561)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.access$400(Schema.java:87)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Field.<init>(Schema.java:541)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Field.<init>(Schema.java:580)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.addAvroRecordField(AvroData.java:1114)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectSchema(AvroData.java:910)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectSchema(AvroData.java:732)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectSchema(AvroData.java:726)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:85)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:63)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$3(WorkerSourceTask.java:321)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
    ... 11 more
[2022-10-10 07:53:57,012] INFO Stopping JDBC source task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask)
```

That means the way I am trying to map the json to Avro is not correct. I need to know how to map the department.deptId to the Avro.

Comment: JDBC Source doesn't support JSON columns, or nested object records. Your schema must be `"name": "json_obj", "type": "string"`, then you can use other tools like ksqlDB to parse to Avro later